# Accessibility: aria-describedby and its use of id attribute in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, aria

Is there an alternative to using id for [aria-describedby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute) in LWC?

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: see my below answer. The solution is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you go to the last part of this doc page you will find the answer. Looks like it is a manual process using .bind() in the rendered callback.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_accessibility_attributes